# Why multiprocessing works in the same thread in Linux Python

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing, window

I am running the following python code on Linux in VMware.

```
import threading
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def task1():
    print("process1:", os.getpid(), "thread1:", threading.get_ident())

def task2():
    print("process2:", os.getpid(), "thread2:", threading.get_ident())

if __name__=='__main__':    
    p1 = Process(target=task1)
    p2 = Process(target=task2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

The output is :

```
process1: 17106 thread1: 140006283367232
process2: 17107 thread2: 140006283367232
```

I would like to make use of two CPU cores for the parallel program running, but they look working on the same thread? Does this mean they are only working on one CPU core?
Or the thread ID being the same does not really mean they are working on the same thread, because they are actually running on two different processes?

I tried the same code in Windows. The output is:

```
process1: 18156 thread1: 23484
process2: 26452 thread2: 25688
```

They are working on different threads and different processes. What is the reason for the different outputs from the two OS platforms?

Comment: `threading.get_ident()` says nothing about thread. Try `threading.get_native_id()`.

Comment: They are not the same thread since they exist in different processes. Clearly the value returned by `threading.get_ident()` is not unique across processes.